# Chrome randomly opening new blank tabs

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome

Starting a few weeks ago, Chrome has started randomly opening new blank tabs. It happens mostly when I open an application from the dash, but not every time. I've tried removing Chrome and re-installing and clearing all my cookies from Chrome. I haven't figured out any other patterns to this, but it's pretty annoying. Has anyone else seen this and might know a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be your online accounts. Sometimes Ubuntu loses access to the Google (or another) account and needs re-authorization.

Go to **System Settings...** from the Gear/Power icon on the top right corner.

click on **Online Accounts** under "personal" and press the **Grant Access** button for the accounts that are turned off.

Let me know if it works, by comments below.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did just re-update all my online accounts and it hasn't happened today. They all lose sign-on so frequently that I have somewhat stopped bothering. When the next warning message pops-up, I'll see if that's the issue. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I agree. I am thinking of disabling some of these Online Access once and for all. Sometimes the problem is triggered by some WiFi hotspots may laptop tries to connect to. The connection does not work, but the online account access is triggered and it fails. The next time, even if the WiFi connection is successful, the online access has to be manually granted.

Comment: I had a site expire today and then the pop-ups started. I'm filing a bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1215709